# Akka shutdown TCP actor

Tags: scala, tcp, akka

In the following code

> GSM mock unbound

is never logged, even though the "disable" message was sent to the server. How can I properly unbind an akka tcp server?

```
class GsmRouter extends Actor {
  import Tcp._
  import context.system

  val name = this.getClass().getName()
  val logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(name)

  def receive = {
    case "enable" => IO(Tcp) ! Bind(self, ConfigurationUtils.gsmRouterAddress)
    case "disable" => IO(Tcp) ! Unbind
    case Unbound =>
      logger.info("GSM mock unbound")
    case Bound(localAddress) =>
      logger.info("GSM mock bound to " + localAddress.getHostName() + ":" + localAddress.getPort())
    case CommandFailed(Bind(_,localAddress: InetSocketAddress, _, _)) =>
      logger.info("Could not bind to " + localAddress.getHostName() + ":" + localAddress.getPort())
      context stop self
    case Connected(remote, local) =>
      logger.info("Client connected to GSM mock")
      val handler = context.actorOf(Props[ConnectionHandler])
      val connection = sender
      connection ! Register(handler)
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The actor that sends you the `Bound` message is actually the one that also manages the binding. If you want to unbind the socket, just send `Unbind` to that actor. Just add a `socketActor: Option[ActorRef]` field to your actor class and change your code to sth. like

```
class GsmRouter extends Actor {
  import Tcp._
  import context.system

  val name = this.getClass().getName()
  val logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(name)
  var socketActor: Option[ActorRef] = None

  def receive = {
    // ...
    case "disable" =>
      socketActor.foreach(_ ! Unbind)
    case Bound(localAddress) =>
      socketActor = Some(sender)
      logger.info("GSM mock bound to " + localAddress.getHostName() + ":" + localAddress.getPort())
    // ...
  }
}
```

Comment: Could you be more precise? I don't get it where to add the socketActor field. Thanks!

Comment: Ah! Actually that was what I already figured out. Thanks anyway :)